# Edge and Chrome showing wrong font when export PDF from OZ viewer or print

Tags: pdf, fonts

Edge and Chrome show the wrong font when exporting PDF from OZ viewer or print.

The web page shows Korean text fine, but I cannot export it as a PDF or print it.

Web page:

[image: The web page show correct font]

Print function:
[image: The print preview show wrong font]

How to fix this problem? I remember I installed Adobe Acrobat then this problem came.